# Youtubeplayer have video but no sound after boot

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm using YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2 as a movie player in my native android app. My app is working kiosk mode and player is part of ui. First after boot app starts as home and plays a video. But after boot there is no sound but only video. After a couple of minutes if restart my app then there is sound and video again.

Android version: 6
YT player: YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi-1.2.2
playermode: YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.CHROMELESS

I don't no what i'm doing and being searching for a while what bug is. Can someone tell what i'm missing?

thx in advance!

Lutfi Uzun

**UPDATE**

MANIFEST:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<activity
    android:name=".ManasMaestro"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
</activity>
```

ACTIVITY:

public class ManasMaestro extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    YouTubePlayerView _playerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.player_view);
    _playerView.initialize(mYoutubeKey, this);

}


@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    Log.e("on", String.format("%s, Error: %s", getString(R.string.error_failed), YouTubeInitializationResultHelper.getError(errorReason).toString()));
    isYoutubePlayerReady = false;
}


private final YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        // Log.e("on", "onBuffering");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        if (appSettings.isWifi() && !mYouTubePlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mYouTubePlayer.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
        Log.e("on", "onPlaying");
        //LUTFI
        if(mCurrentPlayingVideo != null)
        {
            // save current playing...
            if(mVideoCDCover != null)
            {
                //mVideoCDCover
                Glide.with(getBaseContext())
                        .load(mCurrentPlayingVideo.getThumbnailMediumURL())
                        //.override(130, 94)
                        .centerCrop()
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.avatar_loading)
                        .error(R.drawable.avatar_error)
                        .into(mVideoCDCover);

            }
            PlayHistoryVO item = new PlayHistoryVO();
            item.setPlayDate(new DateTime(System.currentTimeMillis()));
            item.setVideoId(mCurrentPlayingVideo.getVideoId());
            mPlayHistory.add(item);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        //Log.e("on", "onSeekTo");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
        Log.e("on", "onStopped");
    }

};

private final YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onLoading() {
        Log.e("on", "onLoading");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaded(String s) {
        Log.e("on", "onLoaded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdStarted() {
        Log.e("on", "onAdStarted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoStarted() {

        Log.e("on", "onVideoStarted");

    }

    @Override
    public void onVideoEnded() {

        Log.e("on", "onVideoEnded");

        // There is no payed music playing
        isPlayingPayedVideo = false;

        // play next if there is one...
        playNextFromList();

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        Log.e("on", String.format("YouTubePlayer - onError : %s", YouTubePlayerErrorReasonHelper.getError(errorReason)));

    }
};
```

}

```
com.google.android.youtube.player W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/app/YouTube/lib/x86
com.google.android.youtube.player W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /system/priv-app/GmsCore/lib/x86
com.google.android.youtube.player W/art: Suspending all threads took: 64.788ms
com.google.android.youtube.player W/art: Suspending all threads took: 28.910ms
com.google.android.youtube.player E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: (unknown) Media progress reported outside media playback: NEW
com.google.android.youtube.player E/AudioAttributes: Invalid stream type -2147483648 for AudioAttributes
com.google.android.youtube.player W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: (unknown) setKeepScreenOn should be through player Surface, not SurfaceHolder
com.google.android.youtube.player W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://r2---sn-5hnedn7e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?lmt=1454848264690147&gcr=nl&sver=3&requiressl=yes&upn=hPWguP6BOnw&xtags=tx%3D9417361&source=youtube&pl=17&mime=video%2Fmp4&key=yt6&nh=IgpwcjA0LmFtczE1KgkxMjcuMC4wLjE&itag=22&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cgcr%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cnh%2Cpl%2Cratebypass%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cxtags%2Cexpire&expire=1456277978&ratebypass=yes&signature=78026A157AE16EC482052EC735A70EEA688B30E2.0EB835FDE622C1A8CA43BDCC19736A60DD8B5059&fexp=9414875%2C9415293%2C9416137%2C9416164%2C9420452%2C9422596%2C9423661%2C9424413%2C9425003%2C9426895%2C9427390%2C9427773%2C9428290%2C9428397%2C9428606%2C9428767%2C9428998%2C9429167&ms=au&id=o-AOW5MhxvjYXiZoaHyvk7DJrGfgMdDpt2R1NdEelbKfqn&dur=193.352&mv=m&mt=1456256215&clen=80164131&ip=31.151.213.145&initcwndbps=1121250&gir=yes&mn=sn-5hnedn7e&mm=31&ipbits=0&dnc=1&cpn=6vDYNGJACP--qgK5
com.google.android.youtube.player W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: (unknown) setKeepScreenOn should be through player Surface, not SurfaceHolder
com.google.android.youtube.player W/MediaPlayer: info/warning (3, 0)
com.google.android.youtube.player W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: (unknown) Warning: unexpected playback play 0 surpressed
```

Comment: Can you provide logs or code snippets that can help the community with the issue? For the meantime, you can check out the [Sample Applications](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications) bundled with the YouTubePlayerAPI to see if you've missed something on it.

Comment: Youtubeplayer:
02-16 21:49:47.682 4360-4380/com.google.android.youtube.player E/AudioAttributes: Invalid stream type -2147483648 for AudioAttributes
02-16 21:49:47.741 4360-4360/com.google.android.youtube.player E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: (unknown) Media progress reported outside media playback: PLAYBACK_PENDING

Comment: how can add code i only can add 255 chars.

Comment: You can edit your main post to add the logs, don't forget to format it properly.